# Red5 media server: How to get rtmp working on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, red5, rtmp

I successfully installed red5 media server on Amazon EC2 instance: windows 2008 server.

I edited the property file (red5.properties) and configured it to run on port 80.

When I hit the ip, I'm able to see red5 welcome page.

All is fine till here but I'm not able to get rtmp working via my app. Do I have to open/configure rtmp port on EC2? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the solution. Red5 RTMP communicates on port 1935. Go to security groups -> select your security group -> Inbound -> Add a Custom TCP port for 1935 (0.0.0.0/0).